# Issues running local host after setting up SSL Certificate through Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, openssl, localhost

My localhost does not display anything, just a white screen. The only thing I had done to my web app before all this was set up an SSL Certificate through Azure using a free ssl cert site and openssl.

I get an error as well on the cmd when i enter "ng serve" to get the localhost up and running, although it does still compile successfully.

The error is "openssl config failed: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory".

This is my first time asking a question on here and I am very new to programming so let me know if I left anything out or if you need more info. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem LJones - we'll try to help you but need a lot more information. Can you open up Chrome Developer Tools in your browser and paste any errors you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17261 . Removing OPENSSL_CONF from Envirnonment Variables should resolve the issue. You may need to reboot your machine for the changes to take effect depending on which version of Windows you are using.